# How to make links shown in phonegaps childbrowser open in Safar?

Tags: html, mobile, cordova, sencha-touch, phonegap-plugins

I have a phone gap app which loads an HTML 5 app in a child browser. Links which are on the pages loaded in the child browser also load in the child browser. I would like these links to open in Safari. How could i do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add this in your AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSURL *url = [request URL];

    // Intercept the external http requests and forward to Safari.app
    // Otherwise forward to the PhoneGap WebView
    if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"http"] || [[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"https"]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
        return NO;
    }
    else {
        return [ super webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType ];
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Childbrowser 2.0.1 does not have an AppDelegate.m. Do you know how to get it to work for the new version?